# React input phone toggle flag visibility

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following `react-phone-number-input` ( https://github.com/catamphetamine/react-phone-number-input ) component:

```
type PhoneNumberInputProps = {
  disabled: boolean | undefined,
  label?: string,
  id: string
  onChange: any
  value: string
  error?: any
}

const PhoneNumberInput: React.FC<PhoneNumberInputProps> = (props) => {
  const {
    disabled,
    id,
    onChange,
    label,
    value,
    error
  } = props

  const [updatedValue, setUpdatedValue] = useState(value)
  const DEFAULT_COUNTRY_VALUE = 'GB'

  const handleONChange = (val: string) => {
    setUpdatedValue(val)
    onChange(val)
  }

  return (
    <PhoneInputWrapper showFlag={false}>
      <Label htmlFor={id}>{label}</Label>
      <PhoneInput 
        disabled={disabled}
        id={id}
        defaultCountry={DEFAULT_COUNTRY_VALUE}
        value={updatedValue}
        onChange={(phone: string) => handleONChange(phone)}
      />
      {error ? 'error' : ''}
    </PhoneInputWrapper>
  )
}

export default PhoneNumberInput;
```

and I am trying to toggle the flag visibility like so:

```
export const PhoneInputWrapper = styled.div`
    .PhoneInputCountry {
        display: ${p => p.showFlag ? 'auto' : 'none'}
    }
`
```

but I am getting the following error:

[image]

Comment: There is no `auto` value in `display` style attribute. Did you mean `block`?

Comment: @technophyle yes block

Comment: Does changing it solve the problem?